# When using "%ld", "D" shows up after a number

Tags: c

I am currently reading The C Programming Language (1st ed). In section 1.5, under Character Counting, the book shows you how you can count the number of characters.

```c
#define EOF -1

main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;

    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

When I type

```
abcdefghijkl
13
```

This is right. abcdefghijkl is 12 characters and \n is 1 character.

But when I do something like

```
qwer
5D
```

`D` pops up when I do character counts under 10. Where is `D` coming from?

---

edit 1: Not sure if it is relevant but I am using gcc compiler on Mac.

Comment: Does `^D` show up in its place if you remove the `printf` entirely?

Comment: No, D doesn't show up when I commented printf line out

Comment: I can recreate this and it's totally bizarre. Adding a period "printf("%ld.\n", nc);" makes it go away.

Comment: You are right Charlie. With the period, when I type `qwer`, I get `5.`. So no D comes out.

Comment: Does not happen when stdin is coming from a file. clang and gcc on MacBook. Gut says it's something about the Ctrl-D EOF coming from the keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried with a different compiler? (Just in case this happens to be a weird gcc bug)

Comment: How do you stop the input?

Comment: Ctrl+D to stop the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just your terminal showing you your EOF character `^D` (the `5` is just covering up `^`, and when it's double digits it's covering up all of `^D`). If you do:

```
echo qwer | ./myprogram
```

You'll see it's not there.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. Also, if you comment out the `printf` like then the command prompt will cover up the `^D`.